# How to print a Panel Page?

Tags: 7, theming, panels

I am using the [Print](http://drupal.org/project/print) module.

I have enabled the node/%node template in panels and used a selection rule to select my specific node type and added fields into the panels regions etc. That all works fine.

I need to be able to use the Print module to see a print-friendly version of this node. However when I go to /print/[nid] I just get a completely blank page.

So is it possible to have a printer friendly version of a panels page? i.e in a template file or another method?

Comment: I don't recall needing to do anything the last time I used the Print module w/ Panels.

Comment: Yeah I just tested on clean site. It does work w/ panels. It must be another module causing something to go wrong here. Thanks. However i'd also need some information that isn't directly related to the node, such as a view for example (which has been added to the panel). For this do I need to render a view into the node template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help above.

Coding was the last option I wanted to take here. In the end I achieved what I needed without it.

Firstly, I configured the Print module to also print non-standard node pages (so panel pages and views as well). Still would not work.

So, I created a copy of my panel with the url 'node/%node/print-friendly' and used panels stylizer to style it very bland. Then I was able to link to the copy panel as '/print/%node/print-friendly' and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the piece of code [here](http://drupal.org/node/565856#comment-6588796). Just copying it here for reference

Create a function as follows in template.php

```
function get_panel_view(&$node) {
    // Load my task plugin
    $task = page_manager_get_task('node_view');


    // Load the node into a context.
    ctools_include('context');
    ctools_include('context-task-handler');
    $contexts = ctools_context_handler_get_task_contexts($task, '', array($node));

    $output = ctools_context_handler_render($task, '', $contexts, array($node->nid));
    if ($output !== FALSE) {
        return drupal_render($output['content']);
    }
    // Otherwise, fall back.
    return drupal_render(node_view(node_load($node->nid)));
}
```

Template should be called print--node--.tpl.php and you can print it as

`print get_panel_view($print['node']);` in place of `print $print['content'];`

Rebuild theme cache